# How do I create a menu?

Tags: python

I want to create a menu that can choose options and display different things depending on the input.

My non-working code:

```
option2=("2.")
option3=("3.")
option4=("4.")
option5=("5.")

print("1.")
print("2.")
print("3.")
print("4.")
print("5.")

ans=("what would you like to do?")
if ans=="1":
    print("answer1")
if ans=="2":
    print("answer2")
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you never ask for input... Please read some Python tutorials for beginners, there are many problems with your code...

Comment: hello Thomas Keig! Welcome to Stack Overflow. The goal here is to make a library of knowledge via specific Q+A pairs, and not to have any "debug/write my code" questions. With that in mind, could you tell us what your problem is and what you have tried to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
ans = ("what would you like to do?")
```

To:

```
ans = input("what would you like to do?")    # Need to use input() function if we want to read input from stdin (console).
```

Answer (score 0):

`ans=("what would you like to do?")` here you assign string instead of reading stdin. Use `ans = input("what would you like to do?")`

Comment: Not a tuple. Single-element tuple needs a comma. This is just an expression in parentheses.

Comment: @h4z3 Thanks. Updated